# how to add edit option the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have just started using angularjs. I am trying to build simple single page app. I have user adding items to list. I display the list using `ng-repeat` like this..

```
<div ng-repeat="option in options"></div><div id="editor"><input type="text" /></div>
```

I have an editor div to add options at the bottom of the list.

```
<div id="item1">item1<a href="#" ng-click="edit_item(item1)">edit</a></div>
<div id="item2">item2<a href="#" ng-click="edit_item(item2)">edit</a></div>
...
<div id="editor"><input type="text" /> ....<div>
```

But when I edit I want to move the `editor div` right after div that I am editing. I tried using jquery `insertAfter` method. It works.

```
<div id="item1">item1<a href="#" ng-click="edit_item(item1)">edit</a></div>
<div id="editor"><input type="text" /> ....<div>
<div id="item2">item2<a href="#" ng-click="edit_item(item2)">edit</a></div>
...
```

But when I add a new item, it does not move `editor div` it does work as expected. Is there a better way to accomplish this using angularjs directive. I thought I can create a class directive and move the editor into a template and load it on click. Will it work? I appreciate any help.

Comment: How you add new items to the list, pushing the new element to options? You'd better provide more code for better debugging.

Comment: @rebomix yes i am pushing the option into object on add. on edit i am setting the field values to scope variable

Comment: how about creating a demo app on plnkr.co or jsfiddle then we can take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can place divs `<div id="editor"><input type="text" /></div>` into repeater.

```
<div id="item1">item1<a href="#" ng-click="edit_item(item1)">edit</a></div>
<div id="editor1" ng-show='...'><input type="text" /> ....<div>
<div id="item2">item2<a href="#" ng-click="edit_item(item2)">edit</a></div>
<div id="editor2" ng-show='...'><input type="text" /> ....<div>
```

etc.

Comment: it would work.But it isn't one input field as show above. the editor has many fields. I would think there would be a better way to accomplish the same

Comment: Why? You can incapsulate editor with all fields in directive and insert directive into repeater.